# Start Tomcat from Eclipse in port 80 in Ubuntu with Authbind

Tags: linux, eclipse, tomcat

I have installed Authbind to run Tomcat on port 80 in Ubuntu.

I have followed http://netthink.com/?p=362 to run Tomcat in Ubuntu in port 80.
When I run Tomcat on the command line by typing `./start.sh`, Tomcat starts normally on port 80 without any exception.

In order to run Tomcat from Eclipse I installed the Tomcat plugin from `http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html`. Everything is fine except that when I want to start Tomcat from Eclipse. When I run Tomcat from Eclipse by the Tomcat plugin, I get the following exception:

> java.net.BindException: Permission denied :80

And if I add Tomcat as a server in "Server view" in Eclipse and want to start it from Server view I get this exception:

> Port 80 required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost is already in use

But I am sure that there is not any process that acquires port 80, because in the same time when I run Tomcat on the command line by typing `./start.sh`, Tomcat starts normally on port 80.

How do I run Tomcat from Eclipse on port 80?

Using another port other than 80 and less than 1024 for Tomcat and start it in Server View in Eclipse gave me the same exception. For example, for port 82:

> Port 82 required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost is already in use

Answer (score 0):

You said :

> *But i am sure that there is not any process that acquires port*
>   80,because in the same time when i run Tomcat in command line by
>   *typing ./start.sh ,tomcat starts normally in port 80.*

Did you stop Tomcat in command line before starting it with Eclipse ?

To make sure your Tomcat is stopped, type this :

```
ps -ef|grep tomcat
```

You should have something like this if Tomcat is stopped :

```
user 16428 16373  0 13:56 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
```

Comment: Yes, I am sure that Tomcat is stopped.

Comment: Using another port other than 80 and less than 1024 for Tomcat and start it in Server View in Eclipse gave me the same exception ,for example for port 82: " Port 82 required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost is already in us"

Comment: I always use port 8080 for Tomcat. Why don't you try this port ?

Comment: I myself always use port 8080,but i want to run a special app that only run on port 80.Because if i want to log in to app it redirects to 443 and when i fill my username and password and enter log-in button  it redirects me to port 80.In order to work i must manually change port 80 to 808 in each page.

Comment: Do you have apache running at the same time ?

Comment: No,i have stopped Apache by command "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop" and also kill all process of Apache by "sudo kill -9 processId".As i said in my previous comment,using another port other than 80 and less than 1024 for Tomcat and start it in Server View in Eclipse gave me the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

try running eclipse as root and then start tomcat (on port 80).. should work. although not an optimal solution. But should work since 80 is a privileged port in linux and requires sudo permissions to run.

Answer (score 0):

You should start eclipse with:
 `authbind --deep eclipse` 
Since eclipse doesn't start tomcat via *startup.sh* file, inserting authbind there will have no effect.